# Reopen request for my question

Tags: support, closed-questions, duplicates, questions

Someone closed my question as a duplicate of another question, but mine is more specific. I cannot understand the reasons behind this.

[Which are the proprietary and paid games for linux do you know - Commercial games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8606/which-are-the-proprietary-and-paid-games-for-linux-do-you-know-commercial-games)

Answer (score 5):

I believe your question was closed because any answer mentioning paid games would need to be duplicated on the [existing question about all games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available). This just creates extra effort and redundancy: why have something in two places when you could have it in just one?

If for some reason you want specifically commercial games, [an answer for the question yours was marked as a duplicate of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available/7458#7458), specifically talks about [LinApp](http://lin-app.com/category/games) - a website that specialises in listing commercial linux applications.

It could also be argued that there are few reasons to want only paid or commercial games - the majority of people will want the best value for money games - of these some will be free, some will require payment.

Comment: Guy ! my ask is NOT A DUPLICATED ! I don't want talk about games that are free... Man, you are forcing me to divide a post we others !? Please ! NO ! I want to focus ! Please, understande me !

Comment: It *is* a duplicate. You are asking about commercial games, the other question was asking about all games. Commercial games are a subset of all games, therefore your question is a subset of the other question. Quite a few of the games posted there are commercial, so it would be duplicating the effort to post a question specifically about commercial games.